# What is the limit of this multivariable function?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have the function:
http://uploadpie.com/7VL6o

Along the y path and the x path, the limit is 0, but what other paths can I try?

Comment: Maybe use the parabola $x=y^2$, or $x=3y^2$.

Comment: Thanks so I get a limit 1/2 now, which means limit DNE. However, how  can I express the limit notation. Would it be, lim (y^2, y) -> (0,0) ?

Comment: I think it is best to use words.